# Error JavaScript loop array

Tags: javascript, html

**I tried to write a very simple array in JS, but when I run the file nothing is displayed in browser, I tried every browser, I also did same examples for arrays before this one and they all ran fine, but this is showing nothing in the browser**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script type = "text/javascript">

var array1 = new Array(3);

           for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {

             array1[i] = prompt("Enter a value");

           }

          document.write(array1 + "<br>");
</script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `int` is not a keyword in JavaScript. Open the browser's error console to see the error messages.

Comment: Please use `console.log(array1)` at the bottom of the script to see what is in the array.

Comment: Learn about the Developer Tools Console and how to read errors messages. It will point you to the problem in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript has no type definitions. You should write `for (var i = 0; ...` in the `for` loop. With `console.log(..)` you can easily debug your script. If you have problems with your javascript code, just open the browser console to see the errors. Hope that helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script type = "text/javascript">

var array1 = new Array(3);

           for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {

             array1[i] = prompt("Enter a value");

           }

          document.write(array1 + "<br>");
</script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: works for me.  I added a snippet for proof.

Comment: @chryb, oh thanks it was a silly mistake, but document.write() is working

Comment: @Aamir, I know, but I think `console.log` is the easiest way to debug your code.

Comment: @Aamir, can you accept the answer? That could be helpful for others with the same problem.

Comment: @Chryb, or r u looking for some reputations, haha, just kidding.